# error in the Wave function of the tuneR package in R

Tags: r, wav, tuner

I am building a script in R for selecting WAV files. However, in the last few lines, when I try to use the Wave function of the tuneR package to determine the audio file configuration it does not recognize the function.
I need this function to be able to save my final file to the output directory, how do I get this?

```
library(seewave)
library(tuneR)
library(warbleR)                                                                                                                          
library(monitoR)

input_dir <- setwd("D:\\teste")!
output_dir <- setwd("D:\\teste_saida")!

setwd(input_dir)

lis.files<-dir(".", pattern="wav")

list.sample.lucas<-sample(lista.arquivos)

list.sample.lucas.01<-list.sample.lucas[1:4]

for (i in lista.aleat.lucas.01){  
  audios <- readWave(i, from = 0, to = 60, units = c("seconds"), header = FALSE, toWaveMC = TRUE) 
  audios2 <- Wave(left=channel,rigth = channel, samp.rate=audios@samp.rate, bit= audios@bit) 
  file_novo<-paste("Lucas_01_", lista.aleat.lucas.01, sep="") 
  setwd(output_dir) 
  writeWave(audios2, file_novo, extensible = TRUE)
  setwd(input_dir) 
}
```

> audios2 <- Wave(left=channel,rigth = channel, samp.rate=audios@samp.rate, bit= audios@bit)

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  unable to find an
> inherited method for function ‘Wave’ for signature ‘"function"’

I hope to be able to list my wav files, randomly select 2 files and save as WAV file in the output directory.

Comment: The code isn't a fully reproducible example since it will not run as it is. However, I can see that there is a typo in the parameter to the call to `Wave`. It should be `right` not `rigth`. Also, what is in the variable `channel`? This is probably being confused for the function `tuneR::channel`.